# Setting unique URL names for nested documents

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

My content tree goes somewhat like this

Articles

- 2016

  - 1

    - Article 1
  - 2
  - ...
- 2017

  - 1

    - Article 1
  - 2
  - ...

Is there any way to make Umbraco pick unique URL names for "article 1"?

As for no it gives me "/articles/2016/1/article-1" and "/articles/2017/1/article-1" which by itself is not wrong.
But I would rather have it do like "/articles/2016/1/article-1" and "/articles/2017/1/article-1-1".

The reason for this, is that I'm currently suppressing the year and month in the URL's, but would like to maintain the tree structure in the backoffice.

Comment: You can write your own contentfinder, and maybe you can use the ID of the node in the url, like /articles/article-[idNode]/ .
Look here https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2014/urlprovider-and-contentfinder/ from some examples of content finder

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Eyescream, I've thought about that approach, however it would expose the ID in the URL which is unwanted, as I want to go for a more "pretty"-url structure.

I can see that "-1-1" is not optimal. However the articles, in theory should not get same names. though should it happen, I would like it not to crash or  malfunction.

Comment: You can try with umbracoUrlAlias to override manually you page alias.
Just create a property with umbracoUrlAlias of type textstring, Umbraco will use that alias in the url instead the default one.

Comment: @MarioLopez any way to make that automatically create a new name if it conflicts with existing content? I can't rely on the content editors to keep track of this themselves.

Comment: You could try adding an event handler to the ContentService.Saving event and do some logic to check for conflicts and generate new aliases? You could even try this way to modify the page alias itself instead using the umbracoUrlAlias:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/events/application-startup

Comment: @MarioLopez, thank you. I'll have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not out of the box. By default, the Umbraco UI will ensure unique naming of pages AT THE SAME LEVEL.

So if you already have a page called "Page 1" and try to add one of the same name at the same level, Umbraco will automatically rename it "Page 1 (1)".

It doesn't check the rest of the site though, just the level that you're adding the content on.

To accomplish what you're after, you'd be looking at some kind of event handler on the content service or something similar, and check there for other nodes with the same name at any level.